# get input fields twice, one hidden

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a simple web application in RoR (ruby 2.2.2). So I build a user control page where I can invite different users. Therefore I build a input field and a 'add user' button. When the add user button is clicked, the value of the input field is copied in a extra created input field beneath (via javascript). So everything worked fine, since today. Now everytime when I open the user control page, next to my wanted input field, is a extra input field which is hidden & has the same id as my wanted input field. I really no not know what I did and how I get rid of this field.

So here is my rails code:

```
<div class='col-md-12'>
  <%= form_for @project, html: { class: 'form-horizontal project' } do |f| %>
      <% unless @project.persisted? %>
          <%= fields_for :invitations do |invitation|%>
              <%= invitation.text_field :email, { value: '', name:'invitationfield', class: "typeahead form-control", size: 50, placeholder: "max.mustermann@student.hpi.uni-potsdam.de" } %>
          <% end %>
          <input type="button" id='AddOneMoreUser' class='btn btn-default btn-xs' value="Add new User">
          <div id="invitedUser"> </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit nil, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', default: t('helpers.links.cancel')),
            projects_path, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
inviteInitUser = ->
  count = 0
  $('body').on 'click', '#AddOneMoreUser', ->
    console.log 'clicked'
    email = $('#invitations_email').val()
    $('#invitations_email').val('')

    div = document.createElement("div")
    div.id = 'user' + count

    deleteButton = document.createElement("input")
    deleteButton.type = 'button'
    deleteButton.value = 'Remove Invitation'
    deleteButton.id = 'delete' + count
    deleteButton.name = 'deleteInvitationButton' + count

    newInvitation = document.createElement("input")
    newInvitation.value = email
    newInvitation.name = 'invitations[' + count + ']'

    div.appendChild(newInvitation)
    div.appendChild(deleteButton)

    list = document.getElementById("invitedUser")
    list.appendChild(div)
    count += 1

    $(deleteButton).on 'click',  -> deleteInvitation()
    return


deleteInvitation = ->
  deleteButtonCount = $("input[type=button][clicked=true]").prevObject[0].activeElement.id
  deleteButtonCount = deleteButtonCount.split('delete')[1]

  list = document.getElementById("invitedUser")
  elem = document.getElementById("user" + deleteButtonCount)
  list.removeChild(elem)



ready = ->
  if $('#AddOneMoreUser').length
    inviteInitUser()
  return


$(document).ready ready
$(document).on 'page:load', ready
```

So maybe someone knows where my error is . Here is a picture of my input field next to this 'hidden' one:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any extra hidden field. Can you highlight it please.

Comment: At the very bottom of your Javascript code, you are adding two event listeners waiting for the document to be ready/page load. Is that your intent? You typically only want such code to run once, not twice.

Comment: ^I guess OP is doing so to enable the javascript to be loaded via turbolinks. though the second line would be suffice. 

@threxx: Are you sure that there isnt any other javascript causing the field to be created twice, that two one hidden? Because this doesnt seem to do that.